# OpenCV giving different result for different operating systems and different mobile devices

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have done some sequence of operations on an image using OpenCV C++. On desktop, I am getting better result but when I ported the same native code to Android, it is giving different result, which of no use for me.

Moreover, the result varies from mobile device to another, i.e. in one mobile model the result which I am getting is different from the other mobile model.

My Code is as follows:

//For Android

```
int processingHologram(Mat img,Mat& output)
{
    Mat gray,dst,gaussianBlur,imageEmboss;
    Mat kernel,kernelEmboss;
    Point anchor;
    double delta;
    int ddepth;
    cvtColor(img,gray,CV_RGBA2GRAY);
    gray=imageCropNew(gray);

    // Initialize arguments for the filter
    anchor = Point( -1, -1);
    delta = 0;
    ddepth = -1;
    kernel= (Mat_<float>(5,5) <<
             1, 1, 1, 1,  1,
            -1, 1, 1,  1,  1,
            -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,
            -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  1,
            -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1 );

    filter2D(gray, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
    //dst=dst/2;
    //gaussianBlur= dst.clone();

    dst=dst+56;
    filter2D(dst, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    GaussianBlur(dst, gaussianBlur, cv::Size(3, 3),0);
    addWeighted(dst, 4.5, gaussianBlur, -3.5, 5, gaussianBlur);
    gaussianBlur=gaussianBlur+56;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_DILATE,Size(3,3), Point(0,0) );
    //morphologyEx(gaussianBlur, gaussianBlur, MORPH_TOPHAT, element, Point(-1,-1), 1, BORDER_CONSTANT,morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
    dilate(gaussianBlur, gaussianBlur, element );
    kernelEmboss=(Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
                      -1,  0, 1,
                      -1,  0, 1,
                      -1,  0, 1);

    imageEmboss=Mat(dst.rows,dst.cols,CV_32SC1, Scalar(0));
    filter2D(gaussianBlur, imageEmboss, ddepth , kernelEmboss, anchor, delta, BORDER_ISOLATED);
    imageEmboss.convertTo(output, CV_32SC1);
    //dst.convertTo(output, CV_8UC1);

    return 0;
}
```

//For Desktop

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ImageCropNew.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "updateMag.h"
#include "computeDFT.h"
#include "computeIDFT.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ImageCropNew.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "updateMag.h"
#include "computeDFT.h"
#include "computeIDFT.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 


/** @function main */
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Declare variables
  Mat src, dst, diagonal, imageEmboss;

  Mat kernel;
  Point anchor;
  double delta;
  int ddepth;
  int kernel_size=3;
  char* window_name = "filter2D Demo";

  int c;

  /// Load an image
  src = imread( argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cvtColor(src,src,CV_RGBA2GRAY);
  src = imageCropNew(src);


  imshow("Source Image", src );

  if( !src.data )
  { return -1; }

  /// Create window

  namedWindow(window_name,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);  


  /// Initialize arguments for the filter
  anchor = Point( -1, -1);
  delta = 0;
  ddepth = -1;


  kernel= (Mat_<float>(5,5) <<
            1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 
            -1, 1, 1,  1,  1, 
            -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, 
            -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  1, 
             -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1 );

  // Apply filter
  filter2D(src, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );    

  diagonal= dst.clone();

  dst=dst/20;
  dst=dst+56;
  filter2D(dst, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);

  dst=dst/2;
  Mat image;
  cv::GaussianBlur(dst, image, cv::Size(3, 3),0);  

  cv::addWeighted(dst, 4.5, image, -3.5, 5, image);
  filter2D(dst, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);

  image=image+56;



  Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_DILATE,Size(2,2), Point(0,0) );


  dilate( image, image, element );
  imshow("Dilation",image);

  Mat kernelEmboss=(Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
            -1,  0, 1, 
            -1,  0, 1, 
            -1,  0, 1);


  filter2D(image, imageEmboss, ddepth , kernelEmboss, anchor, delta, BORDER_ISOLATED);
  imshow("Image Emboss",imageEmboss);
   Mat kernel45degree=(Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
            4,  -2, -2, 
            -2,  4, -2, 
            -2,  -2, 4);


  filter2D(imageEmboss, diagonal, ddepth , kernel45degree, anchor, delta, BORDER_ISOLATED);
  Mat finalResult=image-diagonal;

  char name [50];

  imshow("Diagonal",diagonal);

  imshow("Final Result",dst);

  sprintf(name,"diagonal.jpg");
  imwrite(name,diagonal);    
  waitKey(0); 
  return 0;
}
```

In desktop the visibility of the result is better as compared to mobile.

Can any one have any idea about how to get consistent result on different mobile models and identical result as on desktop?

Comment: It is important you post your code or give some more details regarding what it is you are doing. And, of course - give more details on the problem - what different result are you talking about? Is i s frame rate? Is it quality?

Comment: You are not speaking about a photo that you capture with OpenCV, do you?

Comment: I captured an image using mobile and then supplying the image to my code, but getting different visibility on desktop and mobile for the same code.